# Start-Marker from GeoJSON polyline

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have a map with some walking- and bike-routes and popups with a few details and a picture.

Now I want to set a marker on the first vertex of a GeoJSON polyline, but I can't find out how.

I'm new to Leaflet/Mapbox, and I put my map together from code snippets.

The map, as it is now, is available **[here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57482/much/index.html)**.

Comment: Your Dropbox link shows an error (404)...

Comment: sorry... now it works

Answer (score 1):

@alexgleith is correct.

Get the first coordinate out of each feature and then create the marker

```
var coords = mtb.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post', 'marker-color': '0044FF'}),
    title: 'My Bike Route'
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a separate Geojson with your points and add it the same way you add others hikings routes (below ).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it by getting the first coordinate out of each feature.

I have a line feature in GeoJSON and I can use this to get the first coordinate out:

```
//response is the response from an AJAX call
response.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]
```

So you could just iterate through your features (which you probably do already) and create another layer from the first coordinate.